# How to customize style of numeric "li" in css

Tags: html, css

I have to customize this element - http://gyazo.com/d1ff34edc28a5d2f15068a4a523aecce
to this view 
http://gyazo.com/8d191a943bef6da9df1b2fd3cc9be56b
How can I do this

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this yourself?

Comment: Pseudo-elements and counter-resets ( a search on SO will help you)

Comment: i was searching for solution for a 30 minutes, and didnt find what i need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll search for pseudo-elements and counter-resets

Comment: check SO carefully you will find a lot of counter-increment examples. check this URL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186849/counter-increment-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below, hope it will work :)

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: section;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello world!</li>
  <li>Hello world!</li>
  <li>Hello world!</li>
  <li>Hello world!</li>
  <li>Hello world!</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made an example for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZakharDay/k3rb2x4s/

```
ol {
    counter-reset: li;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

ol > li:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Duplicate

[CSS : Styling the content of before pseudo element on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226602/css-styling-the-content-of-before-pseudo-element-on-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution but I'm not sure can you change color of bullet (tested in chrome)

```css
ol{
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left:0;
}
li:before{
    content: '';
    display: inlie-block;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 2px;
    z-index: -1;    
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li>Text 2</li>
    <li>Text 3</li>
    <li>Text 4</li>
</ol>
```